# convert attachments of type winmail.dat (TNEF) to "real" attachments in stored email messages, recursively in MailDir

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression, email, recursive, conversion

Some email messages contain the attachments in a format called [TNEF (Transport_Neutral_Encapsulation_Format)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Neutral_Encapsulation_Format). This attachment is usually called [`winmail.dat`](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/microsoft-outlook-tnef.html). [Extraction tools](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tnef) exist for linux, but originally these are meant to be opened by Outlook.

I have a large directory hierarchy with stored mail in MailDir format.

How would I best go about to:

- Best detect messages in sub-folders containing winmail.dat
- Cut out the winmail.dat, unpack it
- "reassemble" the email.

I can sort-of imagine a "crude/naive" way, something with grep/perl for finding/cutting, lots of temporary files, and then catting extracted/7bit_converted pieces back together into a (hopefully) valid email structure.

Can somebody think of a better way, perhaps using more appropriate tools. I'd also be interested in any Got-Chas you can come up with, or first-hand accounts of similar endeavors.

In my wildest dreams, somebody here has written/seen use of some cool framework in e.g. python to accomplish something like "Recursively frobnicate some_property of eMail in MailDirs matching some_condition".

Replacing the "meat" of that with something that calls `tnef -xyz` would serve my immediate need, but having a nice "example" like this will surely be useful for lots of other use-cases not only for myself.

Comment: It depends on how badly you want this solved.  You could write a Perl script to inspect and convert the messages, there are modules on CPAN for everything you need.  It might take you a day to read the relevant standards, another day to write the code, and yet another day to debug it.  Make backups first. :)